# Why am I not able to take an Ant build while my Weblogic server is turned on?

Tags: java, ant, weblogic, jndi

With my server set to running or debugging mode, when I execute the usual

```
ant clean build stage
```

in Command Prompt, I get this error message.

```
  BUILD FAILED
C:\Work\lrs\Dev\projects\buildcfg\build.xml:80: Unable to delete file C:\Oracle\
Middleware\user_projects\domains\lrs_domain\lrs\lrsEar\APP-INF\classes\ars.jndi.
properties
```

The build creates fine when I try it after turning my server off. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to turn off the server and run the ant script?

Comment: Obviously your build script needs to delete a file which will be locked by the running Weblogic process.

Comment: @karthick Apart from the obvious extra button presses, the thing is that this used to work before. I WAS able to ant build even while the server was turned on, but I'm getting this error only recently. And I didn't even change any workspace or server settings.